# Wifi connection not working on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, ubuntu-11.10

I have two operating systems installed on my computer [Windows 7 and Ubuntu 11.10]. When I use Ubuntu, my internet connection cannot be used, even though I am already connected to the wifi. In Windows 7, however, my wifi works.
please help me?

Comment: Do you have trouble establishing a connection? or Using an established connection?

Comment: You may want to move this to AskUbuntu...

Comment: I'm using an established connection and I have trouble for it..
I can't use internet connection in ubuntu but I can using it on windows